# Not able to create a flow of functionality in RequireJS

Tags: jquery, requirejs, require

I am not able to create a flow of my functionality using RequireJS. Since I am rookie please bear with me. Below is the snippet I have been trying:

In my HTML file:

```
<script src="assets/js/lib/require.js" data-main="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

In `main.js`:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        pages: '../pages',
        jquery: 'jquery'
    }   
});
define(function (require) {
var $ = require('jquery');
if( $('form').length > 0 ) require('app/form');

});
```

In `form.js` I am just putting an alert to see whether is it being called. But instead I see an error on the console...

```
Error: Script error for: jquery http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror


...,h){c=Error(c+"\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#"+b);c.requireType=b;c.re...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly but `requirejs` doesn't work like `node.js` does which is how you seem to be loading your modules.

In `requirejs` the `define` function is used to declare/define a module and it takes 3 arguments, the first argument is optional, the name you want to call the module, the second argument is an array of the dependencies you need.

In your case your dependencies are `jquery.js` and `form.js`

```
define(['jquery', 'form'], function() {
    // do your thing here.
});
```

If your intention is to just load your form script/module then what you need is the `require` function

```
require(['jquery', 'form'], function() {
    // do your thing here.
});
```

Your form.js file / form module should be defined as follow:

```
define(['deps'], function(){
   // put your alert here
});
```

Comment: Hi Your answer is pretty much informative but I am just checking the flow of the functionality if my Form.js really being called by Require JS. In my Form.js I restructured as above and here is the code : define(['jquery'], function($){
   var content='hi this is a new content';
   $('#tabs').append(content);
});

Comment: But doing the above change; console now shows two errors of the same type which I have been getting and mentioned in the question....

Answer (score 0):

The error you get indicates that RequireJS has loaded your `"jquery"` file but it has not been able to get the JavaScript virtual machine to evaluate it without error. As the [documentation states](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror) this is typically due to an error in the code of the file being loaded. I've had it happen when I had unbalanced curly brackets or parentheses or missing commas, etc. Make sure that your jQuery file is not corrupted.

Comment: I copied the Jquery 1.10 and replaced it with my local file but it still shows the same error...other things I have already mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this code working without any error:

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        jquery : 'jquery-1.10.0'
    }
});

define('myModule', function (require) {
    var $ = require('jquery');
    console.log(typeof $);
});


require(['myModule'], function() {
});
```